# Showing Multiple Graphs w/GWT Visualizations

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization, runnable, asynccallback

This bit of code (below) works to display 1..n LineCharts on the screen without incident.  What I'm wondering is how efficient it is.  I'm calling the `VisualizationsUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, LineChart.PACKAGE)` every time.  Must it be done in this way?

```
public void getData(List<GraphWrapper> graphWrapperList) {
    for (GraphWrapper graphWrapper : graphWrapperList) {
        populateResources.populateResourcesService(graphWrapper.getSeriesWrapperList(),
                new AsyncCallback<GraphWrapper>() {
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        displayDialogBox("*** An Error Occurred ***", caught.toString());
                    }

                    public void onSuccess(final GraphWrapper response) {
                        Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
                            private Widget chart;

                            public void run() {
                                this.chart = new LineChart(createTable(response), createOptions(response));
                                graphPanel.add(this.chart);
                            }
                        };
                        VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, LineChart.PACKAGE);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By loading the `LineChart.PACKAGE`, you're only allowed a single type of chart (`LineChart`). Since you can only load a single "package" at a time, you're stuck with that decision. Try this:

```
VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, CoreChart.PACKAGE);
```

Using the `CoreChart` package, you can load anything that is a child of `CoreChart` (Line, Bar, Pie, Area, Column and Scatter). You can also load any number/combination of the charts. Additionally, you don't need to call the `loadVisualizationApi(...)` method each time, but only the very first time you want to create a chart. Every one thereafter will use that library.

Answer (score 1):

I think loading the LineChart package once should be enough. Did you try running the loop in the callback?

```
public void getData(List<GraphWrapper> graphWrapperList) {
Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            for (GraphWrapper graphWrapper : graphWrapperList) {
                populateResources.populateResourcesService(graphWrapper.getSeriesWrapperList(),
                new AsyncCallback<GraphWrapper>() {
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                            displayDialogBox("*** An Error Occurred ***", caught.toString());
                        }
                        public void onSuccess(final GraphWrapper response) {
                            private Widget chart;
                            this.chart = new LineChart(createTable(response), createOptions(response));
                            graphPanel.add(this.chart);                  
                        }
                });
            }
        }
    };
VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, LineChart.PACKAGE);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the code example of how the answer might be implemented.